# Ionic/Angular nested router-outlet: routerLinks only work once

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, routes, angular-routing

I'm trying to implement a simple example of nested/child routes in an Angular Ionic v5 app, using [Angular's routing guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes). I created a project using `ionic start` and selected the `blank` template, then created two components `ChildAComponent` and `ChildBComponent`. Here's the relevant code snippet from `home.page.html`:

```html
<div id="container">
  <strong>Ready to create an app?</strong>
  <p>Start with Ionic <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
      href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/components">UI Components</a></p>
  <div id="stuff">
    <a routerLink="child-a">Child A</a><br>
    <a routerLink="child-b">Child B</a><br>
    <a routerLink="404">404</a>
  </div>
  <div id="thing">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use the `a` tags to drive what component renders in the `router-outlet`. When I first load the page (URL: `/home`) I can click one of the links and the appropriate child element renders in the outlet. *When this happens*, though, the `href`s on the `a` tags (which I'm assuming are put there by Angular based on the `routerLink`s) ***all change*** to the navigated-to URL.

As such, I can't click on the other component link to render that component without reloading the page (going back to `/home`).

*Before clicking a link (URL is `/home`):*

[image: href's correct]

*After clicking Child A link (URL is `/home/childa`):*

[image]

The Angular docs don't seem to indicate I've configured anything incorrectly, and I can't see anything glaringly different in my code compared to the routing in the [heroes example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/stackblitz.html). What am I doing wrong?

Here's my `home-routing.module.ts` if it helps:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { ChildAComponent } from './childa/childa.component';
import { ChildBComponent } from './childb/childb.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child-a',
        component: ChildAComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'child-b',
        component: ChildBComponent,
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomePageRoutingModule {}
```

---

**GitHub:** https://github.com/zrev2220/router-link-bug

Comment: I can also put my entire project in GitHub if that'd be helpful

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo? I guess you could create it as an Angular project. Also, do you get the same behavior if you replace `a` with `button` tag?

Comment: @AndreiGătej I'll put up a GitHub link and also try to get StackBlitz working (I had halfheartedly tried that before but the file structure they want is different, so it's not a simple copy-paste).

Comment: @AndreiGătej Yes, replacing the `a` with `button` results in the same behavior, though there aren't any `href`s changing values with `button` since `button`s don't use `href`s.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Added GitHub link. Working on StackBlitz.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll have a look tomorrow. But until then, I have 2 questions. Did you manually set the app's base href? What happens if you replace `routerLink="child-a"` with `routerLink="/child-a"` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej `<base href="/">` is in `index.html` (automatically put there, probably by the Ionic CLI). Prepending the slash to the `routerLink`s makes Angular throw an error since all the routes in the app begin with `/home` (from `app-routing.module.ts`).

Comment: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'child-a'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

You'd have to add the **absolute path** to your `RouterLink` directives:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/home', 'child-a']">Child A</a><br>
<a [routerLink]="['/home', 'child-b']">Child B</a><br>
```

---

### Detailed answer

Let's first understand how the `RouterLink`(specifically `RouterLinkWithRef`) directive works. The route it will navigate to depends on the current activated route(`ActivatedRoute`). This is [what happens](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L377) when you click on an element with `RouterLinkWithRef` directive(e.g `selector: 'a[routerLink]'`):

```js
/* ... */
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
/* ... */
```

where `this.urlTree` is defined as a `getter`:

```js
get urlTree(): UrlTree {
  return this.router.createUrlTree(this.commands, {
    relativeTo: this.route, // !
    queryParams: this.queryParams,
    fragment: this.fragment,
    preserveQueryParams: attrBoolValue(this.preserve),
    queryParamsHandling: this.queryParamsHandling,
    preserveFragment: attrBoolValue(this.preserveFragment),
  });
}
```

as we can see, there is `relativeTo: this.route`, where `this.route` is [injected as `ActivatedRoute`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L315).

This is why the problem occurred: when the current route is `/home`, the injected activated route in the directive should be different than the one from `/home/child-*`; in this case, it's the same.

So, when the user first lands on `/home`, the `ActivatedRoute` injected in the directive will have a certain value, let's call it `X`. But when the user goes to `/home/child-a`, the view outside `router-outlet` remains the same, and so does the `ActivatedRoute`'s value. This is important because when dealing with absolute and relative route paths(anything provided to router directives which doesn't have a `/` prepended to it), Angular will traverse the current `UrlTree`(`UrlTree` = the deserialized version of a route path provided as a string) and will try to replace the old part with the new one.
After the user navigates to `/home/child-a`, then in the current `UrlTree` there is no way to find an old part created from the current `ActivatedRoute` in the directive, because `ActivatedRoute` no longer corresponds with the *actual* activated route, so it's *outdated*.

Comment: Using the absolute URLs worked (i.e. `routerLink="child-a"` → `routerLink="/home/child-a"`). However, I'm hesitant to use this fix in a larger app since it "pins" the `HomePage` to the routing configuration in `app-routing.module.ts` (a file that should be outside the concern of `HomePage`, right?). If I want to change the path leading to `HomePage`, I have to modify things in the HTML template in addition to the routing file.

Comment: @Zac I personally don't see it as a significant drawback. The route configurations are most of the times static parts of your app and I don't think it will occur often the case where you have to modify the route paths. And even if you had, I don't think it would take more than a minute. ATM I can't think of other nice solution, but I believe it's worth it to raise an issue, because it seems to be a common situation with a not-so-intuitive solution.

Comment: I tried this logic but when you navigate to another parent base with another nested router outlet and navigate back it still stops working. I made a ticket here referencing your answer. If you could give me any feedback I would appreciate it @AndreiGătej

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317981/angular-router-navigate-only-working-once-on-child-routes