# Angular router.navigate only working ONCE on child routes

Tags: angular, routes

I have a feature module with child routes. The child routes are lazy loaded with their own modules. I see that https://copyprogramming.com/howto/ionic-4-angular-routerlink-only-works-first-time#routerlink-only-works-the-first-time The issue is spoken about but I am not understanding the solution.

The parent component handles the navigation between each child with

```
 viewRoute(path: string) {
        console.log(path)
        this.router.navigate([`./${path}`], {

            relativeTo: this.route,
            state: this.profile,
        });
    }
```

The strange thing is when I refresh the page it works ONCE then every time after that I can log that the function is being called but the navigate throws no errors and does not navigate.

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
```

I have this imported and I see NOTHING happens the second time I call that function it doesnt even try navigate.

```
 this.router.navigate([path],{relativeTo: this.route});

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ProjectsListPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import(
                        '@projects/modules/projects-list/pages/verified-assets/verified-assets.module'
                    ).then((m) => m.VerifiedAssetsModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'solar',
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import(
                        '@projects/modules/projects-list/pages/solar/solar.module'
                    ).then((m) => m.SolarPageModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'asset-backed',
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import(
                        '@projects/modules/projects-list/pages/asset-backed/asset-backed.module'
                    ).then((m) => m.AssetBackedPageModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'initiatives',
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import(
                        '@projects/modules/projects-list/pages/initiatives/initiatives.module'
                    ).then((m) => m.InitiativesPageModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'all',
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import(
                        '@projects/modules/projects-list/pages/all/all.module'
                    ).then((m) => m.AllPageModule),
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

why does this navigation function only work once when navigating between children?

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts it was easier to just drop the ion-router-outlet in my root and then just apply the class ion-page to all my parent components.